# How to write a script auto hide rows when certain date range has passed more than 7 days

Tags: google-apps-script

I am newbie in Google script, and I would like to write a script for the below requirements. I have set the spreadsheet editable.

Here is the link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sDl_umSEJtfQElOCGAgBw0mNDzZ1JGI222h_hVp7YG4/edit?usp=sharing

The goal is to AUTO HIDE the ROW when the date range which is within the row itself (PICK UP DATE & RETURN DATE AS DATE RANGE FOR EVERY ROW) has passed more than 7 days from today/now and assume that the RETURN DATE IS THE DUE DATE.

NOTE: The date format is according US.

I would need this especially when I'll have lots of data in the future. I just need to view current row that is not due yet. I've tried with this one but it hides everything.

Comment: This question is off-topic for a couple of reasons: (1) it can only be understood by visiting an off-site link, which makes it susceptible to link breakage; (2) it is a fairly naked request for free work, rather than mutual assistance. Pro-tips: (a) always demonstrate prior effort and research in your questions here; (b) keep your questions self-contained; (c) don't use all-caps, as readers will think you are shouting at them.

Comment: I appreciate it can be dispiriting to have a question closed Anas, but did the answer from Ritz help you? You can still respond to them by commenting under their answer (and/or upvoting and/or accepting). It is nice to do at least one of these things, since their answer looks helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to correct the date format in your sheet to proper US format (MM-dd-yyyy) for rows 3-5. Try the below script

```
function hideRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = ss.getRange(2, 4,ss.getLastRow()-1).getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<range.length;i++){
      var expiryDate = getexpiryDate(range[i][0]);
      Logger.log(expiryDate)
      var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
      if(expiryDate < today){
        ss.hideRows(i+2);
      }
  }
}


 function getexpiryDate(expiryDate) {
      var result = new Date(expiryDate);
      result.setHours(0,0,0,0);
      result.setDate(result.getDate() +7);
      return result.convertDate();
    }

    Date.prototype.convertDate = function() {
      var mm = this.getMonth() + 1; 
      var dd = this.getDate();

      return [this.getFullYear(),
         (mm>9 ? '' : '0') + mm,
         (dd>9 ? '' : '0') + dd
      ].join('-');
    };
```